# How to pop up a UIView like alert on another UIView?

Tags: iphone

Hi I am new to iPhone development,

I want to Pop up Login page view on an existing view.My application is navigation based application.

Just like alert popsup on a view, in the same manner i want to pop-up my login page.
Please help...

Thanks in advance:)

Regards
Aparna

Answer (score 0):

just add:

```
[self presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];
```

when the login button is pressed, where loginViewController is the controller of the required view to be presented modally.